# How to find total from a concatenated value?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have two concatenated values such as

```
string BreakOut = "10:15 Mintes";
string BreakIn = "10:30 Minutes";
```

I want result as

```
Total=15 Minutes
```

It is a time difference calculation. But values are not in a time format it is in a string format. How can I do this. Please suggest a way. I tried like

```
 TimeSpan span=Convert.ToDateTime(BreakOut ).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(BreakIn ));
```

Comment: There is no point to parse them to `DateTime`. They would be better as a `TimeSpan` since they are _time interval_.

Comment: If 10:15 represents 10 hr 15 min, why you are using Minutes as suffix? I got confused because then I expect the Total to be 15 seconds.

Comment: @L16H7, Its only 10:15 I just add Minutes to understand others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *no point* to parse them to `DateTime` since they are *time interval*. [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan.aspx) would be better choice since it is exactly what this for.

If `Mintes` is typo and your values are *always* the same standard format, you can easily split them with white space and then parse to `TimeSpan`.

For example;

```
var BreakOut= "10:15 Minutes";
var BreakIn = "10:30 Minutes";

BreakOut = BreakOut.Split(new string[]{" "},
                          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
BreakIn = BreakIn.Split(new string[] { " " },
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];

var ts1 = TimeSpan.Parse(BreakOut, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var ts2 = TimeSpan.Parse(BreakIn, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var difference = ts2 - ts1;
Console.WriteLine("{0} minutes", difference.TotalMinutes); // 15 Minutes
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/hvr5Uk)</kbd>.

Comment: @SemilSebastian Since `difference` is a `TimeSpan` it is too normal to see it like `00:15:00`. That means your `difference` has `0` hour, `15` minutes and `0` seconds. You can use it's `TotalMinutes` or `Minutes` properties to get `15` as a double or integer. [`TotalMinutes` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns it as a `double` , [`Minutes` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.minutes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns it as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

if your values always refers to the same day,
you can use something like that :

```
string BreakOut="10:15" ;
string BreakIn ="10:30"; 
double res =DiffInMinutes(BreakIn, BreakOut);
//Total=15 Minutes


        public static double DiffInMinutes(string _BreakIn, string _BreakOut)
        {
            double diff = 0;
            string[] BreakIn = _BreakIn.Split(':');
            string[] BreakOut = _BreakOut.Split(':');
            //timeSpan instanciated with Hours/minutes/seconds
            TimeSpan TimeElapsed = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(BreakOut[0]) - int.Parse(BreakIn[0]), int.Parse(BreakOut[1]) - int.Parse(BreakIn[1]), 0);

            diff = TimeElapsed.TotalMinutes;
            return diff;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I downvoted your question, but maybe you really dont know that there is [TimeSpan.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string breakOut = "10:15 Minutes";
string breakIn = "10:30 Minutes";
string cleanBreakIn = breakIn.Split(' ')[0];
string cleanBreakOut = breakOut.Split(' ')[0];
TimeSpan total = TimeSpan.Parse(cleanBreakIn) - TimeSpan.Parse(cleanBreakOut);
```

Comment: Yup I didint think that much for that a downvote needed???Just you can mention here

Comment: @SemilSebastian your question still has syntax errors and doesnt show that you made any research.